# Subtract a number from a SQL Query in code-igniter framework

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can subtract 1 from a field in my database 
i tried the following but it just set it to "-1", did not actually subtract it.

```
// update listing status to sold
this->db->update("listings", array("cases" => "cases" - 1,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code inserts `-1` in the database because in PHP, `"cases" - 1` evaluates to `-1`.

Try `echo ("any_string"-1);`. Read [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) for details.

In CodeIgniter, you cannot use the the format of the function `$this->db->update` you have used directly to implement this query since the `update` function escapes all values passed to it.

However, you can use the following code to implement the same.

```
//Passing false as third parameter turns off escaping
$this->db->set('cases', 'cases - 1', false);
$this->db->where('id', $id); //Your where condition
$this->db->update('listings');
```

Alternatively, you can write the query manually and use the `query` function.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `listings` SET `cases` = `cases` - 1 WHERE [your where condition]";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->set('cases','`cases`-1',FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', $id);/*whatever condition you want*/
$this->db->update('yourtablename');
```

Heres a link from codeigniter userguide:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html